# gRPC Java: How to know if a client disconnects abruptly (server side)?

Tags: java, grpc

When serving a gRPC client, my server allocates resources which I want to release them when the client disconnect.

My question is: how to properly handle the situation when clients disconnect abruptly?

Comment: If the disconnection is while you are writing data to the response, then the web container will throw a particular IOException, for instance tomcat will throw a `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException`.

Comment: @MartinByers: Oh my bad! Thank you so much for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not an issue, because the Server API is based on RPCs rather than transports.  For example, you can't allocate resources specific to a connection, because the connection isn't exposed to you.

It's a good idea to not base resource decisions on connections, because it breaks down when proxies get involved.  For example, if you have a TLS terminating proxy in front of your gRPC server, all the connections will appear to come from the same "client" even though in reality they don't.

Note: there are ways to approximate a connection (by looking at the client's socket address), but there is no way to know when the connection is gone.  The address is purely informational.

Answer (score 0):

When build your Server, add a ServerTransportFilter that has a method:
 transportTerminated(Attributes transportAttrs).